# MobilePush iOS Error Sending Notification

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush

I have checked out the other questions so far, regarding the "error" under status in mobile push contact.  as usual the message is not helpful, but other posts have said it could be provisioning, but I doubt it because if i install the app through xcode as debug build, i can send, with the same device and push device token, i am able to receive the notification.  However, if i download the same debug build (not adhoc, or production), from a server (we use fabric beta), then i see the Error like the image below [image]

very confused why this is the case, because provisioning is working for sure. Any ideas??? very desperate any help is appreciated

Comment: When you create your build for Fabric, you are creating an archive build, correct? If that is the case, you are creating a build for a different push provisioning - you must use a production cert in that case. Building and running directly from Xcode references development push provisioning, but any archive triggers production provisioning/usage for push.

Comment: Thank you Brian, you're correct, thanks for your tip.  I found the issue, the issue is that yes it is using production cert, and I was using development api key from marketing cloud, that is why it didn't work  if you would post this as seperate answer, i will be glad to accept it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your build for Fabric, you are creating an archive build, correct?

If that is the case, you are creating a build for a different push provisioning - you must use a production cert in that case.

Building and running directly from Xcode references development push provisioning, but any archive triggers production provisioning/usage for push.